# How to operate machine cluster using shell or other commands

Tags: linux, shell

Maybe my problem is not that specific, the following are details

I have 20 machines, the `OS` of them is `Linux`, and I want to implement `Parallel Computing` using a Python's packages, if you don not know that package, that's ok.

And I want to send a file named `start.file` to all the machines, and every machine should run a command to start the `Parallel Computing` service. For example:

```
machine_1 $ my_command start.file
service started ...
machine_2 $ my_command start.file
service started ...
machine_3 $ my_command start.file
service started ...
...
machine_19 $ my_command start.file
service started ...
machine_20 $ my_command start.file
service started ...
```

All the commands are the same, that is `my_command`, and all the `start.files` are the same. The `start.file` is on my localhost, and since `scp` command is not that convenient, and I want to find better method to transfer `start.file` to all the 20 machines.

And I want to find a more automated way to start all the service on all the 20 machines. What should I do to solve that?

Comment: Search for `pssh` and `pscp`. These are parallel versions of `ssh` and `scp` that will operate on multiple machines concurrently.

Comment: It might be worth looking into SLURM (https://computing.llnl.gov/linux/slurm/quickstart.html)